# Find client timezone on server side

Tags: java, servlets

Is there any simply way to get client side timezone from server side in java?

Because my code has control only on server side.

Comment: Your question is too vague at present. Do you have any constraints you wish to share with us? After all, the client could literally send a string to the server with the time-zone information, but perhaps that is not desired.

Comment: Web pages are either static or generated on server side so the server defines what page the client run so from server side you can make the client do what you want, like sending to the server any information it has.

Comment: I agree with user270349, but you can examine the metadata around the transaction.  For example, look at the HTTP headers or the source of the request.  Of course, things get wonky when the request doesn't come from where the actual client is (as in the case of a VPN).

Answer (score 2):

Use java script at the browser / client and send the value to your server.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp

Alternately, use this:
https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect

Comment: That way you get the current offset but not the time zone, a time zone is more than that.

Comment: The time difference between UTC and Local Time, in minutes. I think this info should be sufficient

Answer (score 2):

You can create an applet and fetch client system timezone and get it on server side

Answer (score 1):

If you don't control anything on the client then your only alternative is IP-based geolocation.  Generally this is either handled by a IP to geolocation database or service like [freegeoip.net](http://freegeoip.net/) and a lookup from the geolocation to a timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Some sotware use [geolocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation_software) and then ask the user for confirmation because it seems hard to autodetect time zone perfectly.